# How do I check on the visitor statistics of a website that I do not own?

Tags: web-server, website, web, users

How do I check the visitor statistics of a webpage/website that does not belong to me ?

(for example, I would like to know roughly how many people actually use http://www.askjonskeet.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [alexa.com](http://www.alexa.com/) or [Google Trends for Websites](http://trends.google.com/websites). You will be able to compare a website in question to a website which statistics is already known to you.

Comment: that's 2 cool links !

Answer (score 0):

There is a site http://www.worthofweb.com/ it shows the worth of web and visitors statistics.